# Where should I put showDialog() in my android project?

Tags: android

I am apprerantly getting frustrated...

[I am trying to add a dialog box and it should works if I click any row in the app as attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7vei.png)

public class PlayersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlayersAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

```
private List<Players> myPlayers;

Context context;

public PlayersAdapter(List<Players> playersList) {
    myPlayers = playersList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public PlayersAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
    final MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    holder.playerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            Players players = myPlayers.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You just clicked player " + players.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    holder.playerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            Players players = myPlayers.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You just clicked player Image " + players.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PlayersAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Players players = myPlayers.get(position);
    holder.playersImage.setImageResource(players.getImageId());
    holder.txtPlayers.setText(players.getName());
    holder.txtPoints.setText(Double.toString(players.getPoints()));
    holder.txtRow.setText(Integer.toString(players.getRowNumber()));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myPlayers.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView playersImage;
    TextView txtPlayers;

    TextView txtPoints;
    View playerView;

    TextView txtRow;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        playerView = itemView;
        playersImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlayers);
        txtPlayers = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playerName);
        txtPoints = itemView.findViewById(R.id.points);
        txtRow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowNumber);

    }


    void showDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Receipt");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_warning_24);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want a receipt?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Yes button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }

    void showCustomDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        Button btnLogin = view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        Button btnCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Login Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alert.dismiss();
            }
        });

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alert.dismiss();
            }
        });


        alert.show();
    }
}
```

}

I replaced the line

Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You just clicked player " + players.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

to showDialog() and then my emulator just shut down...

Answer (score 0):

The emulator shut down with a NullPointerException because the `context` isn't initialized.

Please initialize it in onCreateViewHolder method and it will work.

```
public PlayersAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context = parent.getContext();
    // ......    
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer... Can I email you?

Comment: Okay, my gmail is wangkaixuanjc@gmail.com